# Bootstrap navbar active background color when scrolling

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I'm trying to change the background color of Bootstrap navbar item when scrolling due to the section the link leads to (currently it's working only by clicking). I've been reading about Scrollspy but it doesn't work for me. Any help will be appreciated :)

Code:

```js
$(document).ready(function ()
{ 
    $('ul.navbar-nav > li').click(function(e)
    { 
        $('ul.navbar-nav > li').removeClass('active'); 
        $(this).addClass('active');
    });

    $('#logo').click(function(e)
    {
        $('ul.navbar-nav > li').removeClass('active');
    })
});
```

```css
.navbar
{
    padding: 0.8rem;
    background-color: #1C2331;
}

.navbar-nav li
{
    padding-right: 25px;
}

.nav-link
{
    font-size: 1.1em !important;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.navbar-nav > .active > a { 
    background-color: violet;
    border-radius: 5px; 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<nav id="main-navbar" class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark sticky-top">
            <div class="container-fluid"> <!--100% of the screen-->
                <a id="logo" href="#top">
                    <img src="Images/logo.svg" alt="Website logo">
                </a>
                <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarResponsive">
                    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                </button>
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarResponsive">
                    <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link text-light" href="#about">About</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link text-light" href="#portfolio">Portfolio</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link text-light" href="#contact">Contact</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
```

Comment: can you try [mouseover()](https://api.jquery.com/mouseover/) event instead of click()?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please correct code by following :

**1)** Please remove `'text-light'` class from  tag. It should be

```
<a class="nav-link" href="#about">About</a>
```

**2)** Add `data-spy="scroll"` to the element that should be used as the scrollable area (often this is the `<body>` element).

```
<body data-spy="scroll" data-target=".navbar" data-offset="50">
```

**3)** Please update CSS selector :

```
.navbar-nav .active {
    background-color: violet;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
```

```css
body {
    position: relative;
}
.navbar {
    padding: 0.8rem;
    background-color: #1C2331;
}
.navbar-nav li {
    padding-right: 25px;
}
.nav-link {
    font-size: 1.1em !important;
    font-weight: bold;
}
.navbar-nav .active {
    background-color: violet;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<body data-spy="scroll" data-target=".navbar" data-offset="0">
<nav id="main-navbar" class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark sticky-top">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <!--100% of the screen-->
    <a id="logo" href="#top"> <img src="Images/logo.svg" alt="Website logo"> </a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarResponsive"> <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span> </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarResponsive">
      <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
        <li class="nav-item"> <a class="nav-link" href="#about">About</a> </li>
        <li class="nav-item"> <a class="nav-link" href="#portfolio">Portfolio</a> </li>
        <li class="nav-item"> <a class="nav-link" href="#contact">Contact</a> </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
<div id="about" class="container-fluid bg-success" style="padding-top:70px;padding-bottom:70px">
  <h1>Section 1</h1>
  <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling! Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling!</p>
  <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling! Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling!</p>
  <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling! Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling!</p>
  <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling! Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling!</p>
  <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling! Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling!</p>
  <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling! Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling!</p>
  <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling! Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling!</p>
  <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling! Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling!</p>
</div>
<div id="portfolio" class="container-fluid bg-warning" style="padding-top:70px;padding-bottom:70px">
  <h1>Section 2</h1>
  <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling! Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling!</p>
  <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling! Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling!</p>
  <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling! Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling!</p>
  <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling! Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling!</p>
  <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling! Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling!</p>
  <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling! Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling!</p>
  <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling! Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling!</p>
  <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling! Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling!</p>
</div>
<div id="contact" class="container-fluid bg-secondary" style="padding-top:70px;padding-bottom:70px">
  <h1>Section 3</h1>
  <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling! Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling!</p>
  <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling! Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling!</p>
  <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling! Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling!</p>
  <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling! Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling!</p>
  <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling! Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling!</p>
  <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling! Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling!</p>
  <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling! Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling!</p>
  <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling! Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling!</p>
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks! basically it's working, but not in my project. When I tried on a new HTML file it's working perfectly. What can cause this?

Answer (score 0):

Please remove `'text-light'` class from `<a>` tag

Add `data-spy="scroll"` to the element that should be used as the scrollable area (often this is the `<body>` element).

Then add the `data-target` attribute with a value of the id or the class name of the navigation bar `(.navbar)`. This is to make sure that the navbar is connected with the scrollable area.

Note that scrollable elements must match the ID of the links inside the navbar's list items `(<div id="section1">` matches `<a href="#section1">)`.

**Requires relative positioning:** The element with `data-spy="scroll"` requires the **CSS position** property, with a value of "relative" to work properly.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>Bootstrap Example</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<style>
body {
    position: relative;
}
.navbar {
    padding: 0.8rem;
    background-color: #1C2331;
}
.navbar-nav li {
    padding-right: 25px;
}
.nav-link {
    font-size: 1.1em !important;
    font-weight: bold;
}
.navbar-nav > .active > a {
    background-color: violet;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body data-spy="scroll" data-target=".navbar" data-offset="50">
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm bg-dark navbar-dark fixed-top">
  <ul class="navbar-nav">
    <li class="nav-item"> <a class="nav-link" href="#section1">Section 1</a> </li>
    <li class="nav-item"> <a class="nav-link" href="#section2">Section 2</a> </li>
    <li class="nav-item"> <a class="nav-link" href="#section3">Section 3</a> </li>
    <li class="nav-item dropdown"> <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbardrop" data-toggle="dropdown"> Section 4 </a>
      <div class="dropdown-menu"> <a class="dropdown-item" href="#section41">Link 1</a> <a class="dropdown-item" href="#section42">Link 2</a> </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
<div id="section1" class="container-fluid bg-success" style="padding-top:70px;padding-bottom:70px">
  <h1>Section 1</h1>
  <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling! Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling!</p>
  <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling! Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling!</p>
</div>
<div id="section2" class="container-fluid bg-warning" style="padding-top:70px;padding-bottom:70px">
  <h1>Section 2</h1>
  <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling! Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling!</p>
  <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling! Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling!</p>
</div>
<div id="section3" class="container-fluid bg-secondary" style="padding-top:70px;padding-bottom:70px">
  <h1>Section 3</h1>
  <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling! Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling!</p>
  <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling! Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling!</p>
</div>
<div id="section41" class="container-fluid bg-danger" style="padding-top:70px;padding-bottom:70px">
  <h1>Section 4 Submenu 1</h1>
  <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling! Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling!</p>
  <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling! Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling!</p>
</div>
<div id="section42" class="container-fluid bg-info" style="padding-top:70px;padding-bottom:70px">
  <h1>Section 4 Submenu 2</h1>
  <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling! Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling!</p>
  <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling! Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling!</p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: doesn't work in my project somehow, but thanks anyway :)

Comment: Did you remove ''text-light'' class from <a> tag?
Did you update '<body>' tag by '<body data-spy="scroll" data-target=".navbar" data-offset="50">'.